# Optimizing C++ equivalent of Matlab `filter` function

Tags: c++, performance, matlab, signal-processing

Minimum working example below. The Matlab [filter function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) filters the input data `x` using a rational transfer function defined by the numerator and denominator coefficients `b` and `a` and initial conditions `z`. My C++ version of the code is way slower than the Matlab one. My signal `x` is a huge valarray, `a` and `b` are three elements long each and the initial conditions `z` is just three zeros.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::rand;
#include <valarray>
using std::valarray;
#include <ctime>

#define D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1

struct FilterResults
{
    valarray<double> filteredSignal;
    valarray<double> finalConditions;
};

FilterResults Filter(const valarray<double> &b,
    const valarray<double> &a, const valarray<double> &x, const valarray<double> &z)
{
    valarray<double> y(x.size());
    // Pad z
    valarray<double> zOut(a.size());
    std::copy(std::begin(z), std::end(z), std::begin(zOut));

    double Xm, Ym;
    size_t i, n = a.size();
    for (size_t m = 0; m < y.size(); m++)
    {
        Xm = x[m];
        y[m] = b[0] * Xm + zOut[0];
        Ym = y[m];
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            zOut[i - 1] = b[i] * Xm + zOut[i] - a[i] * Ym;
        }
    }
    valarray<double> s = zOut[std::slice(0, zOut.size() - 1, 1)];
    FilterResults r;
    r.filteredSignal = std::move(y);
    r.finalConditions = std::move(s);
    return r;
}

int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    valarray<double> b{ { (double)rand(), (double)rand(), (double)rand() } };
    valarray<double> a{ { (double)rand(), (double)rand(), (double)rand() } };
    valarray<double> z{ { 0, 0, 0 } };
    valarray<double> x( 500000 );
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    {
        x[i] = (double)rand();
    }

    clock_t begin = clock();
    auto r = Filter(b, a, x, z);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "elapsed_secs: " << elapsed_secs << std::endl;
    system("pause"); // C++ is 0.184 seconds on my computer, Matlab is 0.006060.
}
```

Any idea on how to speed it up?

Comment: Welcome to code review I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: Question, what is the order of your filter? It is much better, because of noise effects, to change your higher order filter to a number of cascaded filters with a lower order. In my company, we do (sub)nano precision control, we implement all higher order filters as cascaded filters with either order 2 or 1.

Comment: Would you like an optimized `C` implementation of a Filter function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few highlights:

```
std::copy(std::begin(z), std::end(z), std::begin(zOut));
```

To copy input values to overwrite them is just a waste of time. You will overwrite them then you do not need to copy old values, use `z` instead of `zOut` inside loops.

`y.size()` is possibly evaluated multiple times. It's a minor performance issue (and it *may* be inlined) but it depends on your actual implementation.

I don't know about `valarray<T>` implementation but if this is performance critical you may want to use a plain array.

I hope `FilterResults` constructor doesn't allocate anything (what `valarray<double>` default constructor does?) That said, **this is C++**, filter needs a state then you should design this using a Filter class with its private instance fields. You return just filtered data and you do not create/copy/move status. I *imagine* a `Filter` **class** like this:

```
class Filter
{
public:
    Filter(const valarray<double>& b, const valarray<double>& b)
    {
        // Validate parameters...
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;

        // I omit z, I think there are very few chances you want
        // to set initial filter state...
    }

    valarray<double>& Process(const valarray<double>& input)
    {
        // Your code here, when you're done just return computed
        // result. "Final conditions" (filter status?) has not to
        // be returned, it's a private field.
    }

private:
    valarray<double> b, a, z;
};
```

As you can note some calculations/allocations will be performed in constructor. It won't change anything if each time you filter a different chunk of samples, using different filter, but in the other cases it will allow a big speed-up. Next step in design (to do something in C++) is to abstract away filter and its design: you may have a pure abstract base class `Filter`, an `IirFilter` implementation and one or more classes derived from `FilterDesigner` (let's say `ChebyshevIirFilterDesigner` to calculate filter coefficients). In general to mimic MATLAB approach may result in a sub-optimal implementation (because languages are different and because it will lead to a less than perfect OOP design.) If this class is a use-once function and you want to keep a function instead of a class you may drop `finalConditions`, do you actually use it? If you're implementing an on-line filter (for a continuous stream) then you'd better save it as private field (it's the `z` parameter you're using now)

You should never have `using namespace std;` You already use `std::` consistently then you just add a possible source of conflicts.

Few more notes about performance:

In this case (I guess they do not use any *esoteric* math theory to perform an optimization) C++ performance should be pretty similar or even better than MATLAB. MATLAB may (I do not know what current implementation does) use SIMD/AVX instructions. Do not think you can have same throughput if you don't.

To perform a benchmark is more complex than this! At very least you should setup your machine for that and to perform calculations few thousands times to have an average and a distribution then inspect results to understand caching issues...

Comment: Thanks for the review. Could you elaborate on what you mean by " You return just filtered data and you do not create/copy/move status..."?

Comment: I also added few more notes, what I'd suggest is to take a look to an existing implementation from one of the DSP libraries out there. It's a great source of inspiration. If you're really go for performance you may also take a look to SIMD/AVX to speed-up calculations and, for example, OpenMP to make them parallel (if you have to filter more than one stream).

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're already using the highest optimization level in your testing.
If not, then you are testing apples versus oranges because MatLab functions
will be optimized.

*NOTE:
All optimization suggestions assume that the compiler isn't doing the optimizations
and may or may not improve performance, it may not be portable to other operating
systems or computer architectures.*

Adriano Repetti is providing some good advice about the `std::copy()` and 
about plain arrays. It may also be useful to experiment with `std::array<double, SIZE>` 
that allows you to use iterators. To make the algorithm work as it is now it only
needs to copy the first 2 values of z to zOut.

**C #define versus C++ const or const experssion**
The code has

```
#define D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
```

Two things about this statement

1. It's not used anywhere in the code presented
2. The C++ way of handling this would generally be

   constexpr int D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS = 1;

C++ has 2 ways of defining constants, `const` and `constexpr`.
Of the 2 methods `constexpr` is more like #define than const because 
constexpr is a compile time construct where const is a runtime construct.
You might find more information at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346879/const-vs-constexpr-on-variables).

**Direct Access vs Indexing**
This line in the code can possibly be optimized *if the compiler isn't optimizing
it for you*:

```
        y[m] = b[0] * Xm + zOut[0];
```

The optimization is to use an iterator or pointer to `b[0]` and `zOut[0]`, or to 
create variable to replace `b[0]` and `zOut[0]` since `b[0]` never changes and
`zOut[0]` should only change once and you can pre-calculate the value of `zOut[0]`.

```
    double bZero = b[0];
    double zOutZero = bZero * x[0] + z[1] - a[1] * y[0]; // this may not be quite correct
    size_t i;
    size_t n = a.size();
    size_t mMax = y.size();
    for (size_t m = 0; m < mMax; m++)
    {
        double Xm = x[m];
        y[m] = bZero * Xm + zOutZero;
        double Ym = y[m];
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            zOut[i - 1] = b[i] * Xm + zOut[i] - a[i] * Ym;
        }
    }
```